# How can I automate a Topshelf interactive service install?

Tags: topshelf

I have a couple Topshelf services that run under a specific service account. If I install the services manually from a command line, I can use the --interactive flag, and a dialog box comes up allowing me to enter the username and password. I'd like to be able to automate this through a Powershell script.

Does anyone know how to do this? (Not concerned about Powershell specifically, but with how can I provide the username and password in any installation script.)

As Travis mentioned, I took a look at the command line options. Almost working for me, but now I have one escaping issue. To install, you can type, e.g.,
MyService.exe install -username:Foo -password:Bar.

However, I have to provide both the domain and username for the username option (I know this from doing the --interactive route):
MyService.exe install -username:mydomain\$myusername -password:Bar

I cannot find a way to escape this that works! Sorry -- my question has morphed into something else, might need to mark it answered and open a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Travis pointed me in the right direction with the command line options. I had one more problem with the service account username I had, which was prefixed with a "$": domain\$myuser. I could not find a way to escape it so the "install" command would accept it.

We created a similar username "myuser" (without the $). Now this works just fine:

```
MyService.exe install -username:domain\myuser -password:Bar
```

Comment: I didn't know $ would be a problem. I'm not sure if it's a shell problem or our command line parser. Worth looking into.

Comment: Travis, I suspect it's something not being handled by the TopShelf command line parser (based on a quick look at the code), but I haven't had time to step into it yet myself.

Comment: Try -username "domain\$myuser" instead of the : syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The username and password are configuration in the app.config for services in my setting. This is used in the service setup block in the `RunAs`.

Additionally, there are other [command line options](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html) for Topshelf. I don't know if the documentation is 100% up to date but it's a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how can I automate the installation? I do the same as you (setting username and pwd with RunAs...), but when installing the service to run under a specific account you are prompted to provide the username and pwd -- I want to automate this.

Comment: If the username and password are specified on the command line during install, it should not prompt for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers:

See this url:

https://kristofmattei.be/2015/01/15/topshelf-install-powershell-get-credentials/

Here is the important quote from the url above

## Start Quote

```
So the best version is:

$credentialsOfCurrentUser = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter your username & password for the service installs"
$networkCredentials = $credentialsOfCurrentUser.GetNetworkCredential();
$username = $credentialsOfCurrentUser.UserName
$password = $networkCredentials.Password

Now that we have those variables we can pass them on to the install of the Topshelf exe:


. $pathToServiceExe install -username `"$username`" -password `"$password`" --autostart


Notice the backticks (`) to ensure the double quotes are escaped.
```

## End Quote